# Disabling component source tab on Tridion 2011 SP-1

Tags: tridion-2011

We have a client that has a requirement to disable the source tab on components, they want to force them to use the GUI fields only and not mess around with any source.

Whilst this is easy to accomplish for rich-text fields I cannot find a configurable way of doing it for the whole component.

I'm presuming I'm going to have to modify the GUI somehow and make the source tab only viewable by administrators (or a specifically created user group). What I lack is a) the knowledge on how to do this and b) knowing whether this can be done via a method I'm unaware of.

Any help appreciated as I've not had to customise the GUI since 5.2 SP1.